# How to get tf tensor value computed in loss function in keras train_on_batch without computing it twice or writing custom loop?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model and I've implemented a custom loss function something along the lines:

```
def custom_loss(labels, predictions):
    global diff
    #actual code uses decorator so no globals
    diff = labels - predictions
    return tf.square(diff)

model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=opt.RMSprop())

...

model.train_on_batch(input, labels)

#
```

How to get `diff` after I've run `train_on_batch` without causing
it to rerun predict a second time behind the scenes(unnecessary slowdown) and mess up with trainable/batchnorm etc(possible problems)?

I want to avoid making a manual raw tensorflow train_op loop etc, keeping track of learning phase and whatnot. [Is this my only choice](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html)?

I'm using tensorflow 1.14's keras module

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it(discovered control dependencies and remembered variables)

Basically, I create an assign diff to a variable operation, and with the help of control_dependencies force tf to do this operation every time op is calculated, this way when I get this variable, it doesn't cause graph recalculation

```
diff_var = tf.Variable()

def custom_loss(labels, predictions):
    diff = labels - predictions
    diff_var_op = diff_var.assign(diff)
    with tf.control_dependencies([diff_var_op]):
        return tf.square(diff)
```

test code

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
var1 = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32)
var2 = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.float32)
counter = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32)
var2_op = tf.square(var2)*counter

diff_var = tf.Variable(10, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)

diff = var2_op - var1
diff_var_op = diff_var.assign(diff)

with tf.control_dependencies([diff_var_op]):
    op = tf.square(diff)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print('diff var:', sess.run(diff_var))     #10
print('counter:', sess.run(counter))       #1
print('op:', sess.run(op))                 #9
print('diff var:', sess.run(diff_var))     #3
print('-')
counter_op = tf.assign_add(counter, 1)
print('counter:', sess.run(counter))       #1
print('diff var:', sess.run(diff_var))     #3  #still the same
print('var2:', sess.run(var2_op))          #4
print('-')
sess.run(counter_op)
print('after counter_op')
print('counter:', sess.run(counter))       #2
print('var2:', sess.run(var2_op))          #8
#still the same even though var2 has changed because of counter_op
print('diff var:', sess.run(diff_var))     #3
print('op:', sess.run(op))                 #49 #running full op
print('-')
print('after op')
print('diff var:', sess.run(diff_var))     #7
#variable changed, no operations involved
```

I've posted this question to datascience stackexchange 16 hours ago and did not get any answers, and it turns out there are many more keras questions on stackexchange, so I hoped to get a quicker answer here, while working on it myself.
Not sure what to do with ds.exchange question, will copy answer there as well